# Deleting Record Using ASP.NET Repeater and Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, repeater

I have an entity called PendingPartners which has a navigation property to the Residents entity. I'm returning information from these objects like so:

```
 Dim getSent = (From p In dbContext.PendingPartners _
                       Join r In dbContext.Residents _
                       On p.people_id_des Equals r.people_code_id _
                       Where p.people_id_ini = people_id _
                       Where p.semester = semester _
                       Where p.year = year _
                       Select r.person_name).Distinct
        rptrSent.DataSource = getSent
        rptrSent.DataBind()
```

As you can see above, the data is then bound to a repeater control the code for which looks like this:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptrSent" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnDeletePartner" runat="server"
                    Text="<%# Container.DataItem %>"  />
                <br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Now, I want to make it so that when someone clicks the Delete button it actually deletes that record from the entity - just the PendingPartner portion, no need to rollup to the Resident object.

Now, to do this I think I need to:

1. Add the ID column to the EntitySQL query, e.g. Select p.id, r.person_name.
2. Bind the ID column to the repeater as say CommandName or CommandArgument.
3. Change the way the binding is for the text - since the repeater now has two columns.

I know how to update the EntitySQL, but I always get confused with then getting this info. into the repeater...help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your need to use the bind function in the repeater

The Button's Text uses "person_name" and the command argument uses the "id" and the command name would be "delete".

like so:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptrSent" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="btnDeletePartner" runat="server"
                Text='<%# bind("person_name") %>' CommandArgument='<%# bind("id") %>' CommandName="Delete"  />
            <br />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```